# How to majorate the coefficients of a series function

Tags: complex-analysis

Considering the holomorphic function with its development in series at $0 $  : $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_nz^n$

We suppose that f is converging withing $D=D(0,1)$ and that $∀z ∈ D, Re f (z) ≥ 0$

I have to show that $∀n ∈ N^∗,|a_n | ≤ 2Re(f(0))$.

What I did:

for $0<r<1$ and $n>0$, I proved that:
$a_n=\frac{1}{\pi r^n }\int_{0}^{2\pi}  \textit{Re}(f(re^{it}))e^{-int} dt $

But I have no clue on how to get $f(0) $ in the above formula and use for instance the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality to majorate $|a_n|$.

Any help, hints appreciated.
Thank you